# Change contrast in beamer navigation between active and not active

Tags: beamer, navigation

I want to change the color between the active and not active menu. I can't get it to work! Its too grey. My active font is white, the not active is a little bit grey... I want it whiter...

my LaTeX code:

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0, 94, 156}

% Set up color for header and footer

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=mycolor,bg=white}

\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=white,bg=mycolor}

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary}

\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{parent=palette secondary}
```

I tried `\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}[default][10]`
already but it didnt work. It has no effect?!

Edit:

The whole code:

My test document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}


\mode<presentation>
    {
    \usetheme{test}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent = 28}
    }





\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting

```
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}[default][10]
```

either in the file `beamerthemeutlsb.sty`right before `\mode<all>` or in your test `.tex` file like this

```
\mode<presentation>
    {
    \usetheme{utlsb}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent = 28}
    \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}[default][10]
    }
```

produces the desired effect; here's an image of the headline I obtained from your test file showing the sections with the desired shading (I used the `demo` option for `graphicx` since I didn't have your logos):

[image]

As you can see, section "AAAA AAAA AAAA AAAA" is fully visible and section "WWWW WWWW WWWW WWWW" is below and almost invisible.