# Beamer Title Page: display it like other frames (with header and footer)

Tags: beamer

Is there a way to let my title page look like my other frames.. I just wanna copy the head and bottom part...

You can find my `tex` code here: [Change contrast in beamer navigation between active and not active](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70432/change-contrast-in-beamer-navigation-between-active-and-not-active).

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

From the code shown in [Change contrast in beamer navigation between active and not active](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70432/change-contrast-in-beamer-navigation-between-active-and-not-active) it is possible to notice that the titlepage has been defined as:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Therefore, to let it looks like the other frames, the option `plain` should be removed since it is the option used to hide the `header` and the `footer` of a frame.

Correct code:

```
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Is it possible to hide the section and subsection?`

Comment: I found a solution. I added \setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{} to the frame containing the title page. It works but I am trying to include it in my style file. Cant get it work. Anonyone a idea?

Comment: For this, I think you should open a different question.